# Java check if flags are set in integer

Tags: java, binary, hex, bit-shift

I've got a feeling the answer to this is to bit shift, but I can't quite get my brain to grasp it.

I've got some integer values being read, always different, and I need to check if some flags are set by looking at their bit pattern, for example.

```
Flags:
0x00000002 = Do thing 
0x80000000 = Do another thing

Value: 0x80000002
```

So looking at the value, both flags should be set.  But I'm not sure of the best way to implement this.  I guess I could use `BigInteger.testBit();`, but I don't really want to have to figure out the exact bit in each of the flags (there are a lot).

I can remember doing something like this in C a long time ago, it was something like `if (value & flag)`, but Java doesn't seem to like this.

Any ideas of suggestions, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use bits, you could use AND

```
boolean isSet = (values & mask) == mask;
```

But for a very, very small performance hit (probably not big enough to notice) you can get this same basic principle with [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)

```
boolean isSet = myEnumSet.contains(MyEnumReferencingTheOldIntegerValue)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this will do the trick.  I'll also take a look into the EnumSet.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest solution is the following:

```
if ((value & 0x00000002) != 0)
    // Do thing
if ((value & 0x80000000) != 0)
    // Do other thing
```

You just have to make sure that you're only using one bit per flag. If you are, it's more complicated.